# How to import to substance painter?

Tags: vertices

When I use vertex paint I can Color some of my groupings of objects , but when I switch objects it does not show the Color of the original groupings of objects it only shows what is selected. This is the same for all of my objects. When I export it to fbx it merges all the colours together in a rainbow like pattern. How do I keep my objects colours?

I made a simple building and I coloured the walls different colours.

I imported the fbx into substance painter and baked it and that is when it looked like a rainbow pattern.

I made some cylinders and used them to make a wall. Then I made two cubes into walls for the sides and then I made another cube for the back of the building. I then went to uv editing in object mode and selected the cylinders and made them red in vertex paint mode. Then I selected the walls to the side and made them blue (the red went away). Then I selected the back wall and made it green (all others went back to normal grey Color). I then exported it to a fbx. In substance painter It showed a rainbow and all I could do was set the whole image as a certain Color not the different parts.

Is it the way I am exporting the fbx?  How do I export the fbx so that the different colours show properly on substance painter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is what happens:

[image]

Comment: 'Color Source' is set to 'Vertex Color' in substance painter (*Bake Mesh Maps* dialog)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoqOb.png BTW: You can also set it to 'Mesh ID' in this case and SP will bake an ID map based on that (without any vertex color painting in blender beforehand). Also, please don't ask the same question many times. If you are not getting answers, or the answers don’t help, then edit your original post with more information and detailing what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: It didn’t work the colours were merged together. 

Sorry about that I thought my other post was closed, so I made a new one with pictures.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of taking photos of your monitor take actual screenshots. See [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org), so we don't have to guess if we are looking at a physical issues like reflections or smudges, a hardware issue such as a malfunctioning display, a software level bug or driver, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Looking good (technically). Remaining issue is that you've got overlapping UVs and one material for all objects. *Either* head over to the *uv editing* workspace, select all objects go into edit mode and pack all islands properly **or** create one material for each object and make sure you've got proper UV's. In general: substance painter is a material/texture authoring tool, there is no way around supplying good UVs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/introduction.html/unwrapping/index.html